# GeoServer combine 100+ layers from an external WMS source in a single request

Tags: geoserver, wms

I have an external WMS data source. It is a topographic map, where each map element type (roads, forests, buildings, etc.) is a different layer. In total, there are about 180 layers.

I would like to add them all as a single layer to my GeoServer instance. If I create a layer group with 180 layers, each of them get requested separately each time.

Instead, I would like to request all layers at once from the external WMS by listing them all in the layers request parameter (layers=roads,houses,buildings,...). Is there any way to setup GeoServer to do that, when adding an external WMS source?

Comment: What software is providing the external WMS, if it's MapServer for example you can request the root layer, and get all layers

Comment: I think this would require additional code to written

Comment: The root layer category and subcategories do not have a name attribute, therefore I cannot do a GetMap request for them (is that right?). A 'root' layer GetMap request also does not work.

Layer names are known (named from 0 to 186, need to be layered in that order). Maybe there is a way to modify the GeoServer config files to force accepting a layer named '0,1,2,3,...' (by disabling GetCapabilities checks?)

Answer (score 0):

> Instead, I would like to request all layers at once from the external WMS by listing them all in the layers request parameter (layers=roads,houses,buildings,...). Is there any way to do that?

Yes, you can do exactly that. You can make a GetMap request with multiple layers specified in the LAYERS parameter and a single layer (one image) returned which is a combination of those layers.

The order you list the layers is important, the WMS server will draw the layers so that the first listed layer will be at the bottom.

Compare the outputs of:

`...LAYERS=UKCoShelf_BGS_1M_SBS,GBR_BGS_625k_BLS,GBR_BGS_625k_SLT&...`

[image: LAYERS=UKCoShelf_BGS_1M_SBS,GBR_BGS_625k_BLS,GBR_BGS_625k_SLT]

to

`LAYERS=UKCoShelf_BGS_1M_SBS,GBR_BGS_625k_SLT,GBR_BGS_625k_BLS`

[image: LAYERS=UKCoShelf_BGS_1M_SBS,GBR_BGS_625k_SLT,GBR_BGS_625k_BLS]

In the first you can see some of the bedrock geology (GBR_BGS_625k_BLS) beneath the superficial geology (GBR_BGS_625k_SLT), but in the second the superficial geology layer is completely obscured by the bedrock geology layer.

This is a feature of all WMS servers

A MapServer WMS allows you to have all layers by requesting the root layer.  Layers are drawn according to how they are listed in the service.

[image: LAYERS=BGS_EN_Bedrock_and_Superficial_Geology]

Comment: Thanks for the useful tips, but to clarify my question, the main problem I am having is, that I cannot setup GeoServer to request multiple layers at once from external WMS source. When I add a WMS store to GeoServer, it is only allowed to import and display separate layers. I also could not find any ways to edit the raw configuration files to force it.